# Push Notifications Permissions

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Trying to work around a few corner cases for when push notifications are denied in the app and I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to reset whether the user has seen the notification request pop up?

2) Is there any way to determine if the user has said no to the notification request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) No, unless there's some private API that does that, but that's not allowed by Apple

2) The first time your app is started, after calling **registerForRemoteNotificationTypes**, you can check if **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** is called. If it's not, the user said "No thanks".

Comment: 1) What I thought... grumble
2) the only issue with that is the time span between registerForRemoteNotificationTypes and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is undefined.   I could check it on app exit, but I'm not sure if the user even has to make a choice prior to exiting.   

Also the user could change the notification permissions in Settings and I can't detect that change.

Answer (score 5):

You can always check the status of the permissions if the user changes them, you can check them on `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
     if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]  respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]  isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]){
            NSLog(@"Notifications Enabled ios 8");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Notifications not Enabled ios 8");
        }
    } else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)
        {
            NSLog(@"Notifications Enabled");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Notifications not Enabled");
        }
    }

}
```

updated to make it work on iOS 8 too

Comment: From the docs it seems like that would be set if you'd ask for the alert permission, even if the user had disabled alerts for your app.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, this doesn't set anything, just checks the permission status

Comment: I was thinking it would just report the permissions you had asked to register for previously, but in further tests I think you are right, it reports only the permissions the system granted.

Comment: Yes, it checks the current permissions, I put the code on the applicationDidBecomeActive to check them if you change the permissions on the "Settings" app