# Is didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken called always?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

Is the method `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` called even if the user doesn't 'accept' receiving remote notification?

Comment: Sorry, it is not... unfortunately. 

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587176/push-notifications-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You need to keep track of this manually.  It's fairly basic.  If the user allowed your app to receive remote notifications then this method would have been called once.  You need to persist the token with your user in your server side datastore.  Of course, if they later decide to disable notifications for your app in Settings you are SOL.

Comment: Don't think of it as SOL, just change your app's behaviour accordingly. Remember, it's the user's phone, not yours, and if he/she doesn't want to hear about your app, he/she doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it gets triggered, but you can check what has been enabled with this method:

```
- (UIRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes
```

This SO post has good examples on how to handle most things:
[Remote Notification Token handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672955/remote-notification-token-handling)